# Нумерация строк с нуля

Tags: linux, bash

`cat -n` нумерует с единицы. Подскажите, что умеет нумеровать с нуля?

Comment: А вычесть 1 не вариант?

Comment: @Qwertiy, неа, вычесть не вариант

Answer (score 2):

```
man nl
```

> -v, --starting-line-number=NUMBER

Поэтому:

```
nl -v 0
```